# how to customize a sign in method using Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have an element that derives from IdentityUser which contains a property called AppId. I'm trying to customize the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync, so it includes the AppId (from AspNetUsers where AppId = id).

is this even possible?

what I have so far:

```
public class LCUserManager
{
    public LCUserManager(IdentityDbContext context)
    {
        this.DbContext = context;
    }

    public async Task<IProfile> SignIn(int appId, string userName, string password)
    {
        IProfile result = default;
        PasswordHasher<Profile> hash = new PasswordHasher<Profile>();

        var tmp = this.DbContext.Profiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Active && u.AppId.Equals(appId) && u.NormalizedUserName.Equals(userName.ToNormalized()));

        if (tmp != default)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    public IIdentityDbContext DbContext { get; }
}
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear! What are you actually wanting!

Comment: @TanvirArjel what don't you understand? how to include AppId when authenticating

Comment: In my opinion .You can check the appid via query against the DbContext as you shown before use the standard PasswordSignInAsync . You does't need to override the PasswordSignInAsync method.